# cancelGoal crashes if called before any goal has been sent

Tags: actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

cancelGoal crashes if called before one goal has been sent.

```
OpenPRS comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
[ERROR] [1298889427.632366743]: Trying to cancelGoal() when no goal is running. You are incorrectly using SimpleActionClient
[ERROR] [1298889427.632673206]: Trying to cancel() on an inactive ClientGoalHandle. You are incorrectly using a ClientGoalHandle
Segmentation fault
```

if you send at least one goal, then it just reports the problem but keep running.

```
[ERROR] [1298889509.884434617]: BUG: Got a transition to CommState [PREEMPTING] when in SimpleGoalState [DONE]
```

Is this normal? should I fill a ticket?

(I know, it is stupid to cancel something which does not yet exist... but it should not crash.)

Just to add that cancelAllGoals behaves better and does not crash. It does not even report any error.

By the way, where are the source for these functions (cancelGoal and cancelAllGoals), I cannot find them in my ubuntu virtual box appliance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9229/cancelgoal-crashes-if-called-before-any-goal-has-been-sent.../) by [felix](https://answers.ros.org/users/154/felix/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2011-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Felix, thank you for filing a ticket.

This is now being tracked at https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4836

---

Originally posted by [vpradeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/101/vpradeep/) with karma: 760 on 2011-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Any segfault is worth a ticket.  Please file one at https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/newticket?component=common&keywords=actionlib

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-02-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-11-04**:
@tfoote  im having a problem when i send the goal ac.sendGoal(goal) if i dont put ac.waitForResult(); the goal is not posted or the robot does not move, when i ac.waitForResult(); it does move. But due to this line im unable to post a new goal until the waitforresults ends. do you have any idea why or any ideas on how to solve it? i would really appreciate it

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-11-04**:
This is a new question. Please create a new question with enough detail to reproduce your issue.

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-11-07**:
@tfoote thanks, one last question is there a way to get the position of the robot?